# Parse HTML code with preserving original case

Tags: javascript, angular, html-parsing, jsdom, angular-template

I'm working on an Angular project while I need to manipulate the template file and do some modifications (adding ids and so on), in order to do these modifications I've used JSDOM to parse the HTML files and manipulate their HTML Elements, the problem encountered with JSDOM is that it lowercases all attributes and tag names found on the HTML files and since Angular parser is case-sensitive (unlike HTML parser which is case-insensitive) so it makes sense that I want to preserve all the HTML files original case, is there any option to configure JSDOM so it preserves original case for the parsed HTML documents ? if this is not possible is there any alternative so I can parse the templates code and manipulate its elements using another parser ?
TypeScript code sample for more comprehension :

```ts
        files.forEach(file => {

        let html = fs.readFileSync(file,"utf-8");
        html=html.replace(/%/g,'--pct--'); //Replacing the '%' sign to avoid errors when decoding html file
        html = decodeURIComponent(html); 
        html=html.replace(/--pct--/g,'%');
        console.log(html);
        /*Html original file :
        <ckeditor #ckEditor
        [(ngModel)]="contentWithTags.content"
        [readonly]="false"
        (change)="changes($event)"
        debounce="500"
        *ngIf="items_research && items_research.length>0"
        [config]="ckeConfig">
        </ckeditor>
        */
        console.log("---------------------------------------");
        var dom = new JSDOM(html);
        doc = dom.window.document;
        /* Some manipulation code on document 
        .
        .
        */
        var finalResult = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
        console.log(finalResult);
        /* Final result:
        <ckeditor #ckeditor="" 
        [(ngmodel)]="contentWithTags.content" 
        *ngif="items_research &amp;&amp;   
        items_research.length>0" 
        [readonly]="false" 
        (change)="changes($event)" 
        debounce="500" 
        [config]="ckeConfig">
        </ckeditor>
        */
        fs.writeFile(file, finalResult, err => { //Saving the result file after manipulation
        console.log('done');
        });
    })
```

### EDIT 1 :

I need a DOM parser that parses the HTML code from a string, giving me the whole document with its elements (which is possible on JSDOM) AND preserves the original case of document elements (which is not possible on JSDOM)

Comment: I wonder if jsdom is actually the correct lib to use for something simple like. You might be better of with something like dom-parser, which I think does not touch those attributes..

Comment: Yeah I just need a simple DOM parser which preserves attribute case

Comment: @MikeOne after reading the doc of dom-parser it seems that it uses regex to do the parsing which is not preferable by the community, besides that it has only basic functionalities (getElementByID, getElementByTagName,byName,byClass,byAttribute) which can't really help me, I need a parser that parses the whole document from a string without touch the case of its elements.